# Splitted-pages LaTeX format

Tags: document-classes, books, book-design

Do you remember the book titled [*"Diary of a bad year"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary_of_a_Bad_Year) written by [John Maxwell Coetzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._M._Coetzee) (a Nobel laureated writer)?

If you do not. This book has a special format where each page is horizontally-splitted wherein the upper segment describes some essays while in the lower segment describes a story (as you can see in Figure below).

How can I write a document (in LaTeX) in this *unusual format*? I want to avoid (as possible) use `minipage` or similar LaTeX environments because they may do not support a way to input entire content and distributing automatically along with the book.

[image: Sample of a page of the book "Diary of a bad year"]

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes sound like a good fit for the behaviour that you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

% place holder text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% increase footnote font size
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}

% suppress footnote marker with custom command \blfootnote
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

% full width footnote separator
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hrule}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\raggedleft\hrule\vspace*{2em}}

\begin{document}

\section{Heading}
\lipsum[1-2]
\blfootnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]